# What's under the keg rubber handles?

Tags: corny-keg

One of my kegs have a very brittle rubber handle. Them I realized that I don't know if it is just a rubber piece glued to the keg body or if there is any sort of metal underneath.

If there is just a rubber piece, what to do to repair/recover it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a bit of searching around GIS, but as I thought, looks like there's nothing under there:

[image]

For repair/recover, best option would probably be to clean both sides well with alcohol or Ronsonol, and use something like [JB Weld](http://www.jbweld.com/product/j-b-weld/) to 'glue' it back on. Might help to scuff up both sides (maybe with sandpaper) to help it adhere, too.

Since we're talking about the handles which need to bear the whole weight of a full keg though, I would be very careful carrying it around.

edit -
More evidence:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8aWG.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWr2j.jpg

Comment: Thanks, Franklin. Actually, my problem isn't the attachment of the rubber to the metal, I think it is fine... But the rubber itself is cracking, is very old and dry, I think it has been suffering effects of sun and rain for a long time. But, if there is nothing under them, I think I'll just let it that way, maybe sand it and caulk the cracks to make a smooth feel. My hope was the rubber been around metal handles, so I could simply remove it.